# Renew for OpenAFS does not work

Tags: network

I use OSX 10.8.2 and OpenAFS 1.6.1a. Even I have checked "Enable auto-renew", the ticket allways expires. My settings:

- Seconds before expire to renew: 4000
- Ticket renewal check frequency: 3600

In my understanding, with that setting AFS should always a renew **before** expiring. Do I miss something or is there a bug in OpenAFS?

PS: The tag does not fit very well, but no AFS or OpenAFS tag exists.